# How to allow multiple inputs from user using R?

Tags: r, user-input

For example, if I need that the user specifies the number of rows and columns of a matrix:

PROMPT: Number of rows?:

USER INPUT: [a number]

I need that R 'waits' for the input. Then save [a number] into a variable v1. Next,

PROMPT: Number of columns?:

USER INPUT: [another number]

Also save [another number] into a variable v2. At the end, I will have two variables (v1, v2) that will be used in the rest of the code.

"readline" only works for one input at a time. I can't run the two lines together

```
v1 <- readline("Number of rows?: ")
v2 <- readline("Number of columns?: ")
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can combine those statements into a clause:

```
{ v1 <- readline("Number of rows?: "); v2 <- readline("Number of columns?: ") }
```

Or generally, make them into a function:

```
readlines <- function(...) {
   lapply(list(...), readline)
}
readlines("Number of rows?: ", "Number of columns?: ")
```

Answer (score 4):

You may find useful the [tkentry](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/~wettenhall/RTclTkExamples/editboxes.html) function in package tcltk (for more examples see [here](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/~wettenhall/RTclTkExamples/)). There is also a [guiDlg](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/svDialogs/html/guiDlg.html) function in package svDialogs

```
library(svDialogs)
display(guiDlg("SciViews-R", "My first dialog box with SciViews-R"))
```

Check [this page](http://www.sciviews.org/SciViews-R/) for more..