# Drop down list implementation in R

Tags: r, drop-down-menu

I am using the following code for the Share Price Application I have been developing (with plenty of help from people here that is greatly appreciated!). One of the things it should do is allow the user to pick a company to analyse from stored XML Files, I have been using the following code to do this:

```
df <- xmlToDataFrame(file.choose())
```

Instead of using file.choose () {as apparently the dialogue box reveals to much of the system structure}, it has been suggested to use a drop down menu, with a list of the companies and a link to the file.

Is such a thing possible in R and is there an easy-ish  way of implementating it?

Comment: There is list.files() which lists all files of directory, e.g.: list.files(getwd()) would limit it to your working directory. I know, it's not interactive yet, but maybe you do something out of it. Maybe with the help of the built in http helpserver.

Comment: Check out [this](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/~wettenhall/RTclTkExamples/DropDown.html). Also this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540232/how-to-allow-multiple-inputs-from-user-using-r).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`select.list` allow you to select from a list. Check also `menu`.

Examples:

Using `menu`

```
companies <- c("AAA","BBB","CCC")
links <- c("c:/file1","c:/secret/file3","c:/file3")

i <- menu(companies, graphics=TRUE, title="Choose company")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(links[i])
```

Using `select.list`

```
companies <- c("AAA","BBB","CCC")
links <- c("c:/file1","c:/secret/file3","c:/file3")

i <- select.list(companies, title="Choose company")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(links[companies==i])
```

If you want to show name and link on list then use

```
menu_items <- paste(companies, " (", links, ")", sep="")
i <- select.list(menu_items, title="Choose company")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(links[menu_items==i])
```

Comment: Ok that works from within R. However, when I run it from the Batch file using Rscript it does not work. Is there additional packages / code I should be using?

Comment: `xmlToDataFrame` is in the `RSXML` package.  Do you have that installed for the version of R you are calling in batch mode?

Comment: @Anthony No. It is expected behaviour. From `?menu`: "It is an error to use `menu` in a non-interactive session.". You could try `tk_select.list` from tcltk package.

Comment: @Marek How do I make it interactive? Also how do I link the selected company to its file location?

Comment: @Anthony Help to `interactive` said that (on Windows) you could use `--ess` (but you should use Rterm instead of Rscript). I extend my answer, is this what you meant under "link the selected company to its file location"?

Comment: @Marek The code under select list is what I am looking for. Thanks! Still having trouble with the BATCH file even after the suggestions you made. Rterm opens up R with a warning message that the parameters are ignored and so just starts R. Rscript still just flashes a command box and disappears.

Comment: @Anthony There are small differences between Rterm and Rscript, e.g. `RScript ex.R` is `Rterm < ex.R`. You could read more in [introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scripting-with-R)

Comment: My batch file is currently as follows:


   c:\R\bin\Rterm.exe --ess "c:\Users\user\Desktop\shares.r"   


when I run it I get the following error message:

c:\R\bin\Rterm.exe --ess "c:\Users\user\Desktop\shares.r"   ARGUMENT 'c:\Users\user\Desktop\shares.r' __IGNORED__

Underneath this in the command window R opens up as normal.

Comment: Use `c:\R\bin\Rterm.exe --ess < "c:\Users\user\Desktop\shares.r"`

Comment: @Marek Ok that is working for the most part, it starts going into some sort of infinite loop and I have to kill the process to get it to stop!

Comment: The endless loop, just keeps printing out: [code]Save Workspace Image? [y/n/c]: >Save Workspace Image? [y/n/c]: >[/code] Any way to stop this?

Comment: Sorted the endless loop problem, not by changing the BATCH file so Marek's answer is right (Thanks Marek), but by altering the quit function from quit() to quit(save = "no", status = 0, runLast = TRUE)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to get into `tcltk` programming, try the `gWidgets` packages.

```
library(gWidgetstcltk) # or library(gWidgetsRGtk2), etc.
drp <- gdroplist(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), container = gwindow())
```